# Yii CGridView and default values in CDbCriteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have simple CGridView, which is not showing me any data at all.

I've logged query built by CDbCriteria and there was some LIKE conditions which uses mysql default field values, so MySQL searches for entries with default values in required fields.

Since I have none entries matching this condidion it returns 0 rows. But the thing is, I don't need these LIKEs. Is there a way to disable it?

Here's the view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->name)'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->email), "mailto:".CHtml::encode($data->email))',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Controller:

```
public function actionUsers() {
            $model = new Users();
            $this->renderPartial('users',array(
                'model' => $model,
            ));
}
```

Function Search of model Users:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort'=>array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'user ASC',
                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>5
                    ),
));
```

And Logged Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` `t` WHERE (((((email LIKE :ycp0) AND (`group` LIKE :ycp1)) AND (gender LIKE :ycp2)) AND (city LIKE :ycp3)) AND (name LIKE :ycp4)) AND (av_url LIKE :ycp5) ORDER BY `t`.`name` LIMIT 5. Bound with :ycp0='%NotSet%', :ycp1='%3%', :ycp2='%Secret%', :ycp3='%NotSet%', :ycp4='%NotSet%', :ycp5='%noav.jpg%'
```

Comment: Found this as "patch" http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10424-

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Stackoverflow and don't have sufficient reputation to post a comment, otherwise I would have asked that you share more information on how you configure your CDbCriteria object in your $model->search() function.

But, I suspect that you are using partial matches in the `compare` method, which can be disabled by passing `false` in the `$partialMatch` parameter as follows:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('email', $someValue, false);
```

Or, since `false` is the default value, you can simple write:

```
$criteria->compare('email', $someValue);
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation either to post an aswer on my own question :) But solution was `$model->unsetAttributes();` in controller or the view. Thanks for your response anyways!